# Custom cart count is not updating without reloading in Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have the ajax script enqueued, but I can't seem to get the cart items count updated without refreshing the page.

Functions:

```
// Add scripts and stylesheets
function startwordpress_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'reset', get_template_directory_uri() . '/reset.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/veggiee.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
}

function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    ob_start();

    $fragments['a.cart-customlocation'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'is_product_the_same_cat', 10, 3 );
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="/cart" id="cart_icon"></a></li><li><span class="counter"> 
<?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', WC()->cart>get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?></span></li>
<li id="access"><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'menu-header' ) ); ?></li>
</ul>
```

I have researched the problem and as far as I can see the basket total should update straight away without a refresh.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is some mistakes and missing things in your code. For the cart item count in your header the following will solve the problem.

1) The HTML code in your `header.php` file:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/cart" id="cart_icon"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="counter" id="cart-count"><?php
        $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', $cart_count ), $cart_count );
        ?></span>
    </li>
    <li id="access"><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'menu-header' ) ); ?></li>
</ul>
```

2) Your related hooked function code to enable cart item count **Ajax refreshed**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'refresh_cart_count', 50, 1 );
function refresh_cart_count( $fragments ){
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <span class="counter" id="cart-count"><?php
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', $cart_count ), $cart_count );
    ?></span>
    <?php
     $fragments['#cart-count'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Related: [Ajaxify the cart items count in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123903/ajaxify-the-cart-items-count-in-woocommerce/51126271#51126271)

Comment: That works beautifully, thanks for this. I'll compare the code to what I have so i can actually understand what I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: @Remco Just added an "Id" to the `<span>` tag, cleaned some typo errors, added the hook to your function and added the related code to be refreshed inside the function… See this related thread: [Ajaxify the cart items count in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123903/ajaxify-the-cart-items-count-in-woocommerce/51126271#51126271)

Comment: Thats very helpful, thanks. I got my initial code from https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/ and your explanation is really helpful for any future projects. Many thanks. Also, thanks for editing my question... this helps me to improve any future questions.

Comment: I think I've upvoted that too, no? Or am I missing an upvoting feature?

Comment: @Remco I mean this one: [Ajaxify the cart items count in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123903/ajaxify-the-cart-items-count-in-woocommerce/51126271#51126271) but just if you want/like. Thank you :)