# Ajax update product count on cart menu in Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a menu item that points to the cart and that reads the number of products currently in the cart.

```
CART (3)
```

When, on the cart page, I change the number of products and click the `"Update cart"` button, or delete an item, the number doesn't refresh.
Any idea why?

```
/*CHANGE CART MENU TITLE IN MENU*/
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','my_item_setup' );
function my_item_setup($item) {

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {

            global $woocommerce;

            if ( $item->url == esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ) ) {

                if (is_null($woocommerce->cart)){

                } else {
                    if( get_locale() == 'fr_FR' ) {
                        $item->title = 'PANIER ('. '<span class="count-cart">' .  $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . '</span>)';
                    } else {
                        $item->title = 'MY CART ('. '<span class="count-cart">' .  $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . '</span>)';
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return $item;
}
```

And

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'my_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments' );
function my_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments( $fragments ) {
    // Add our fragment
    $fragments['li.menu-item-type-woocommerce-cart'] = my_item_setup( '');
    return $fragments;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Using [Ajaxify the cart items count in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123903/ajaxify-the-cart-items-count-in-woocommerce/51126271#51126271) answer code, seems to work a little better. The product number updates when I delete an item from the cart page, or when I change the number of items, but it doesn't update when I empty the cart. Moreover, there's a space before and after the product number (see picture with empty cart and `"CART ( 1 )"`.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'wc_refresh_cart_fragments');
function wc_refresh_cart_fragments($fragments){
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <span class="count-cart"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></span>
    <?php
        $fragments['li a span.count-cart'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using AJax to update cart data?

Comment: Does it work Louis?

Comment: I commented your answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

It's better to set a tag ID than a tag CLASS to ajaxify a cart count, as this selector reference need to be unique. If it's not the case, and there is a hidden mobile duplicated menu, it can't work.

So this item menu need to be unique on the generated html code of your page… If this menu item is duplicated in a mobile version, you will need to change the tag ID or the tag CLASS for the mobile code version.

I have revisited your code a bit:

```
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','my_item_setup' );
function my_item_setup( $item ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
        if ( $item->url == esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ) && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ){
            $title = get_locale() == 'fr_FR' ? 'PANIER' : 'MY CART';
            $item->title = $title . ' (<span id="count-cart-items">' .  WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . '</span>)';
        }
    }
    return $item;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'wc_refresh_cart_fragments', 50, 1 );
function wc_refresh_cart_fragments( $fragments ){
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    // Normal version
    $count_normal = '<span id="count-cart-items">' .  $cart_count . '</span>';
    $fragments['#count-cart-items'] = $count_normal;

    // Mobile version
    $count_mobile = '<span id="count-cart-itemob">' .  $cart_count . '</span>';
    $fragments['#count-cart-itemob'] = $count_mobile;

    return $fragments;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should better work.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks. Way cleaner code. The only problem is that I have three occurrences of the cart link `CART (2)`. One  in the desktop menu, one in the mobile menu and one in the mobile header. I just tried using a class everywhere, I see no bugs. But if you recommend using an id, how can I differentiate the code for the mobile menu and the code for the desktop menu, so I can pu two different ids? Because for now my function my_item_setup is replacing the item in both mobile and desktop menus. And with this code, emptying the cart still keeps a number in the fragments.

Comment: @Louis "C'est compliqué ça dis donc!"… I think that you need to add a different Id for each and a fragment for each ID like in my updated answer *(but it's difficult to guess for me without the generated html code)*. If needed you can contact me on skype chat searching for Loïc de Marcé (Paris).

Comment: mmh ok I see. I am going to get back on this tomorrow ! I'll let your know. Thanks a lot Loïc ;)

Answer (score 0):

To Ajaxify your cart viewer so it updates when an item is added or deleted (via ajax) use:

```
/**
 * Show cart contents / total Ajax
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment' );

function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    ob_start();

    ?>
    <a class="cart-customlocation" href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
    <?php
    $fragments['a.cart-customlocation'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
} ?>
```

[Reference Link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, it's been recommended to use WC() instead of $woocommerce for a few times