# Update shortcode display once WooCommerce cart change

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am trying to add an amount count down to my website header until free shipping is enabled.

Here is my code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'setup_free_shipping_counter' ) ) {
    function setup_free_shipping_counter() {
        ob_start();
            ?>
                /* ... */
                <p class="label-active"><span><?php echo get_shipping_cost_progress() ?></span> till free shipping</p>
                /* ... */
            <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'setup_free_shipping_counter');

function get_shipping_cost_progress() {
    $min_amount = 50;
    $current = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    $progress = wc_price( $min_amount - $current );

    return $progress;
}
```

The problem is that on cart Ajax events like Ajax add to cart, remove item from cart, change cart item quantity, the progress doesn't get updated.

How can I make my Shortcode get updated on woocommerce Ajax cart events?

If I reload page then Shortcode shows correct progress, but I need to make it to update dynamically on cart Ajax events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dedicated `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments` action hook (Ajax powered), to get your custom progress count refreshed when cart changes on Ajax requests.

I have revisited your code a bit *(to change the display, when free shipping is enabled)*:

```
// Shortcode: [fs_progress]
function display_free_shipping_progress() {
    return get_free_shipping_progress();
}
add_shortcode('fs_progress', 'display_free_shipping_progress');
    
// Function that makes calculations and display
function get_free_shipping_progress() {
    $min_amount = 100; // Set the min amount to get free shipping

    $prodgress = $min_amount - WC()->cart->subtotal;

    if( $prodgress >= 0 ) {
        return '<p id="fs-progress" class="label-active"><span>' . wc_price( $prodgress ) . '</span> '. __("till free shipping") .'</p>';
    } else {
        return '<p id="fs-progress" class="label-active">'. __("Free shipping is enabled!") .'</p>';
    }
}

// Refreshing "free shipping" progress on cart ajax events
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'refresh_free_shipping_progress' );
function refresh_free_shipping_progress( $fragments ){
    $fragments['#fs-progress'] = get_free_shipping_progress();

    return $fragments;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Shortcode usage:** `[fs_progress]` Or in php code: `echo do_shortcode( '[fs_progress]' );`

---

Related: [Ajaxify header cart items count in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123903/ajaxify-header-cart-items-count-in-woocommerce/51126271#51126271)