# WooCommerce getting custom total refreshed on cart page without reloading

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have functionality that build on total based amount on cart page in WooCommerce.
I get cart items total value with function:

```
WC()->cart->subtotal() - WC()->cart->get_discount_total();
```

**Problem is:**
If user enter coupon or other discount `subtotal()` still give same result **(***without coupons inside***)**.
I noticed if i refresh page, sum is working perfectly.
How I can make this change to be working on ajax cart refresh?

Comment: It's surprising, as far as i know, ```update cart section``` and ```coupon code section``` are using ```ajax``` by default. If you've developed your theme from scratch, then it might be the issue of caching between the pages. It's a common issue for custom built themes that use browser caching to speed up the loading of a page and not updating the elements on a page.

Comment: You need to Ajaxify this totals the same way as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123903/ajaxify-header-cart-items-count-in-woocommerce/51126271#51126271)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Nice! The ```jquery``` part did the trick for me!!! Thank you.

Comment: So you should post that as an answer to your own question with a little explanation may be *(useful for the community)*

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks, i will try.
Will i need to enter specific id header for making it?